# Google cloud build optimization with kaniko

Tags: optimization, google-cloud-platform, build, cloud

While looking through the documentation on gcp's build. I noticed that there are two paths for optimizing the build.
One was using `--cache-from` as shown below

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [
            'build',
            '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/[IMAGE_NAME]:latest',
            '--cache-from', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/[IMAGE_NAME]:latest',
            '.'
        ]
```

And the other was to use `Kaniko`. I am curious how these two paths are different in terms of optimizing the build speed. I think both path caches the layers and starts the build starting from the "changed" layer. Also I'd like to get input on which method ensures faster build.

Thank you!

Comment: it's roughly the same thing. i can't say which one is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Guillaume Blaquiere, both are the same things. But I would like to include [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/speeding-up-builds) link for your reference.